# Mysqli update command not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

```
include('config.php');
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "real");
if ($transaction == "Success" && $currency == "USD") {
    $user_ids = '".$user_id."'; $total_cred = `user_credits` +'".$package_credits."';
    $add = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `user_credits` = ?  WHERE `user_id` =  ?");
    $add->bind_param('si', $total_cred,$user_ids); $add->execute();
}
```

The code doesn't throw out any error nor its updating the database .

Comment: Don't you think your `$total` statement has error?

Comment: total credit= (already credits in account) + The new credits purchased.  ('".$package_credits."') This is the variable which has the recently purchased credits

Comment: What datatypes do these table fields have?

Comment: your syntax is all wrong here `$user_ids = '".$user_id."'; $total_cred = \`user_credits\` +'".$package_credits."';` it's creating the query wrong so the query is failing.

Comment: user id is set to integer in database .And User credits as decimal

Comment: `$user_ids = '".$user_id."';` sets the variable to the literal string `".$user_id."`, since there is no variable interpolation inside single quotes. And `$total_cred = \`user_credits\` + '".$package_credits".";` tries to run the external program `user_credits` and substitute its output into the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the if block to

```
//    $user_ids = '".$user_id."'; REMOVE THE statement
//    $total_cred = `user_credits` +    '".$package_credits."'; REMOVE THIS too
$add = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `user_credits` = `user_credits` + ?  WHERE `user_id` =  ?");
$add->bind_param('ii', $package_credits, $user_id ); $add->execute();
```

Let MySQL do the hard part.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
include('config.php');
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "real");
if ($transaction == "Success" && $currency == "USD") 
{
    $user_ids = '".$user_id."'; 
    $total_cred = user_credits +'".$package_credits."';
    $add = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET user_credits = ?  WHERE user_id =  ?");
    $add->bind_param('si', $total_cred,$user_ids); 
    $add->execute();
}
```